# React Native MapViewDirections: force entire route to remain in view?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-native-maps

I'm following [this guide](https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions) on using `MapViewDirections` in React Native to draw a route between two points on a map. I'm able to keep the start and end points within the view by specifying the `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` based on the coordinates of the start and end point. However, if the route that Google Maps calculates snakes way off to the side, I might end up with a scenario like this where the start and end points are within the view, but the route isn't

[image]

**What I Want To Know:** Is there a way to make the view automatically scale to fit the entire route? My code is analogous to [the tutorial](https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions):

```
<MapViewDireactions
  origin={this.state.coordinates[0]}
  destination={this.state.coordinates[1]}
  apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

U should use `useEffect` for that. Here I am writing the code which executed if origin or destination is changed:

```
  useEffect(() => {
if (!origin || !destination) return;

mapRef.current.fitToSuppliedMarkers(["origin", "destination"], {
  edgePadding: { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 },
}); }, [origin, destination]);
```

You should create `mapRef` like   `const mapRef = useRef(null);`.
Also "origin" is my marker name of start point. And "destination" is my marker name of end point.

Comment: Don't forget add identifier in marker: <Marker identifier="origin" /> with the same name in "fitToSuppliedMarkers(["origin"]"